# Show that of x is in the closure of a set, then there exists a sequence that converges to x

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $X$ and $E \subseteq X$. How can I show that $x \in \overline{E}$ if and only if there exists a sequence $x_n \in E$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$.

Comment: Since it's often the case that the closure of a set is defined as the set of all limits of sequences of points in the set (which is what you're trying to prove), you should provide the definition of "closure" that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The open ball of radius $\frac 1n$ around $x$ intersects $E$